# Finding minimum of array in scheme

Tags: arrays, scheme, racket

Want to move thru the array and remember the smallest value until end of array and then return the smallest one. But am at a loss on how to do this in scheme

```
int smallest = INT_MAX;
for (int i = 0; i < array_length; i++) {
if (array[i] < smallest) {
    smallest = array[i];
  }
}
```

If i want to get the smallest value in a array and in addition also want the next smallest value whilst keeping it in array form

how would this be done in scheme?

Comment: So what is wrong with the code?

Comment: Note that "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself." and that "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."  If you've written code, it's not included here.  What have you tried so far?  The code you showed is fine (except that it's not in Scheme) and it's a fine algorithm.  What have you tried in Scheme so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some standard R6RS implementations (since you wrote Scheme and not Racket in your title ad question). I've commented what to do to get it to work in `#lang racket`

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs base)
        (rnrs lists)
        (rnrs sorting))

;; using vector-sort. Not working in #lang racket
(define (my-min1 vec)
  (if (zero? (vector-length vec))
      +inf.0
      (vector-ref (vector-sort < vec) 0))) 


;; All the rest work on lists. 
;; You may make a wrapper like this (using my-min2 as example)
(define (my-min2-vec vec)
  (my-min2 (vector->list vec)))

;; using min, accepting inexact
(define (my-min2 lst)
   (apply min +inf.0 lst))

;; using base with integers
(define (my-min3 lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      +inf.0
      (apply min lst)))

;; using list-sort. 
;; #lang racket: use sort in place of list-sort and swap arguments.
(define (my-min4 lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      +inf.0
      (car (list-sort < lst))))

;; higher order functions
;; #lang racket: use foldl in place of fold-left 
(define (my-min5 lst)
  (define (min2 x y) 
    (if (< x y) x y))
  (fold-left min2 +inf.0 lst)) 

;; using < and iterating through helper
(define (my-min6 lst)
  (define (my-min6-aux lst min)
    (if (null? lst)
        min
        (my-min6-aux (cdr lst)
                     (let ((cur (car lst)))
                       (if (< cur min) cur min)))))
  (my-min6-aux lst +inf.0))

;; using < and iterating though named let
(define (my-min7 lst)
  (let my-min7-aux ((lst lst)
                    (min +inf.0))
    (if (null? lst)
        min
        (my-min7-aux (cdr lst)
                     (let ((cur (car lst)))
                       (if (< cur min) cur min))))))

(my-min1 '#(3 7 9 1 5))     ; ==> 1
(my-min2-vec '#(3 7 9 1 5)) ; ==> 1.0
(my-min2 '(3 7 9 1 5))      ; ==> 1.0
(my-min3 '(3 7 9 1 5))      ; ==> 1
(my-min4 '(3 7 9 1 5))      ; ==> 1
(my-min5 '(3 7 9 1 5))      ; ==> 1
(my-min6 '(3 7 9 1 5))      ; ==> 1
(my-min7 '(3 7 9 1 5))      ; ==> 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over a vector/array just like you'd normally do:

```
(define (vector-min v)
  (assert (positive? (vector-length v)))
  (let looping ((i 1) (v-min (vector-ref v 0)))
    (if (= i (vector-length v))
        v-min
        (looping (+ i 1)
                 (min v-min (vector-ref v i))))))
```

You could also use a combination of primitive Scheme functions as:

```
(define (vector-min v)
  (apply min (vector->list v)))
```

with the cost being converting a vector to a list.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the implementation.

Professionals programmers will try to avoid reinventing the wheel, and use a function like [min](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._min%29%29), which just works.

Code like the above can be translated "literally", preserving the meaning of the C code:

```
#lang racket
(define smallest +inf.0)
(define an-array (vector 3 1 4 1 5 9 2 6))
(define array-length 8)
(for ([i (in-range 0 array-length)])
  (when (< (vector-ref an-array i)
           smallest)
    (set! smallest (vector-ref an-array i))))
(print smallest)
```

But this is not great stylistic form to an experienced Racket programmer.  Not only does it only work on vectors, but the code is too concerned with indices.

Why not just work on the elements of the thing we care about instead?  Here's what that looks like when we change the focus of the iteration:

```
#lang racket
(define smallest +inf.0)
(define an-array (vector 3 1 4 1 5 9 2 6))
(for ([elt an-array])
  (when (< elt smallest)
    (set! smallest elt)))
(print smallest)
```

This is a little better.

If we were to do something like this in multiple places, it might be worthwhile to see if we can clean it up some more.  In Racket, it's probably better to write this in such a way that you can avoid thinking about the silly loop details over and over.  As a concrete example of how to generalize and clean this up, see the definition of `for/max` [here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket/private/base..rkt%29._for/fold/derived%29%29) (or [here](http://blog.racket-lang.org/2012/10/the-3n1-problem_4990.html)).

The point is, make it work on other things besides just arrays, and if you end up doing it a lot, make it a part of your language.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a list or a vector?

For lists, the `min` function is part of the scheme R5RS standard.

```
(min 5 1 4 23 4)
```

or

```
(apply min '(5 1 3 4 55))
```

or you could roll your own

```
(define my-min
  (lambda lst
    (let loop ((min (car lst))
               (lst (cdr lst)))
      (if (null? lst)
        min
        (let ((x (car lst)))
          (if (< x min)
            (loop x (cdr lst))
            (loop min (cdr lst))))))))
```

For a vector, you could still use these functions along with `vector->list`, if efficiency is not a concern.

Comment: How would i do this with vector->list?

Comment: `(apply min (vector->list my-vec))`

Answer (score 0):

A lot of great answers already, but I think the most straightforward (besides a direct translation)  is to implement a vector-min in terms of the vector-fold provided for in SRFI 43 which is supported by racket.

```
(define (vector-min vec)
 (vector-fold
    (lambda (n v-min next)
      (if (< v-min next) v-min next))
    (vector-ref vec 0)
    vec))
```

http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-43/srfi-43.html#vector-fold

Not sure if the code works, my scheme implementation doesn't provide the full srfi 43 library.